# Skype for Business Microphone Settings

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, microphone, citrix-receiver

I have a very specific setup and a very weird symptome:

My microphone headset (does not matter which, I have tried multiple of them) is connected and on my Windows machine I have a reasonable control over it.

On the Virtual Machine at work however (also Windows, via Citrix-receiver) the Skype recognizes the microphone, but does not listen to it, unless the following menu is open:

```
Control Panel > Sound > Manage audio devices
```

As soon as the menu is open (literally just that) Skype's gauges start responding.

By the way "Exclusive Mode" is off. So "applications are not allowed to take exclusive control of this device"

Does this weird behaviour ring any bell? This is a ridiculous situation.

Comment: "Does this weird behavior ring any bell?" - Sounds like a case of Skype failing to automatically detect the device and assign a default microphone.

Answer (score 0):

check out the Audio Settings for the Citrix Receiver using a Group Policy
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121613